# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication at com.javacourse.springBootDemo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data

I am taking that mistake but I am working to solve the mistake  , really I do not know why I am taking error ? In stackoverflow , there is similar of my error . I tried these but it did not work again. I used java 1.8 jdk and spring boot 2.3.2

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javakerem</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootDemoo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootDemoo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

SpringBootDemooApplication.java

```
package com.javakerem.SpringBootDemoo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDemooApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemooApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

ProductsController.java

```
package com.javakerem.SpringBootDemoo.apiTest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProductsController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String get()
    {
        return "Kerem Kagan";
    }
    
}
```

I can write a little english , i am sorry if i wrote false.

Mistake is that :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at com.javacourse.springBootDemo.SpringBootDemoApplication.main(SpringBootDemoApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: please show the stacktrace (full error message)

Comment: I edited above.

Comment: I edited but my all spring project is same error just group or artifact is different . Error is as above.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634937/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-boot-springapplication

Comment: How are you running this? From the IDE (does it compile or give errors there when typing the code)?

Answer (score 0):

1. cd to THE_PROJECT_FOLDER via the cmd or git bash

   > ```
   > mvn clean
   > maven install
   > maven package
   > ```
2. go to the project using your IDE and go to the class containing the main method
3. Click on the @SpringBootApplication and see to the left an icon like a lamp
4. Click on it and select download with maven
5. run the applcation

Try this it may work fine for you

Comment: I tried these but it did not work again . Do you think is there anything else why it does not work ? Actually , I surprised because I am listening the lesson I am doing the same of teacher I encountered an error.

Comment: No nothing else I ran it in my system it worked fine did you change the version I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes I changed and I made that : I listened my teacher the lesson , I download in there source code , It did not work :) but it worked of my teacher in the lesson. Do you think anything is there else ?

Comment: Show full error trace so that I can guide you more just copy the whole error message shown to you in browser and paste it here in your question

Comment: I edited but my all spring project is same error just group or artifact is different . Error is as above.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check and do let me know if it work for you

Comment: I went my project folder D:\Eclipse2020\springBootDemo in cmd. But how i can write mvn clean in cmd  , so what i will write in cmd when i came in my project folder ?

Comment: yes you can write mvn clean as its spring boot project simply do what I have mentioned please check the project location as you have imported the project so it may be in downloads folder of your system

Comment: in your question's title there is com.javacourse.springBootDemo so please tell me whats this as I can't see it in your files so what is this

Comment: D:\Eclipse2020\springBootDemo>mvn clean
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you used start.spring.io website for spring boot project if not then use it

Comment: Yes I have used .

Comment: so you have selected the maven project then this command must work view above the person have mentioned other question link see if that helps otherwise do a fresh start means create new project