# Spring Boot: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to route the requests in my spring boot to another server.

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.etc.settings</groupId>
        <artifactId>projects</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company.gateway</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <name>gateway</name>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <inceptionYear>2017</inceptionYear>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <pmd.version>3.6</pmd.version>
        <findbugs.version>3.0.3</findbugs.version>
        <spring.boot>1.5.3.RELEASE</spring.boot>
        <swagger.version>1.5.13</swagger.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.7.5.201505241946</jacoco.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> 
</project>
```

Application.properties

```
zuul.routes.foos.path=/r/users/**
zuul.routes.foos.url=http://com.company.sws/c/users/
```

Main Class

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class GatewayApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

I am getting this error when starting application

```
2017-06-20 09:13:42.720 ERROR 15296 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [se.telenor.bapigateway.GatewayApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulConfiguration
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:299)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
        at se.telenor.bapigateway.GatewayApplication.main(GatewayApplication.java:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulConfiguration
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:380)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:314)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: See the root cause: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean`

Comment: Please have a loot at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20740703/1126831).

Comment: check this ---  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284134/java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-introspect-class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean` was deprecated in spring-boot version 1.4 and its replacement, `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean`, was introduced. The deprecated class was removed in spring-boot version 1.5. Something in your app or in one of its dependencies needs to be updated to use the replacement.

Answer (score 4):

for `spring-boot` version `1.5.x` use `Dalston.RELEASE` in place of `Brixton.SR5` in your dependency config:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>Dalston.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to depricated dependency in spring-boot. Use following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

[Please find initial working code](https://github.com/ravindra-yadava/zuul)

Comment: it does not help  fix the problem

Comment: It worked for me can you check suitable dependency from url: (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies) based on usage or compatibility with yours code. Otherwise clone working initial code (https://github.com/ravindra-yadava/zuul/), if still in problem please update i will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Spring Start site](https://start.spring.io/), it looks like the correct Spring Cloud Version for Spring Boot 1.5 is:

- `Edgware.SR5` for `Spring Boot >=1.5.0.RELEASE and <=1.5.19.RELEASE` and
- `Edgware.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` for `Spring Boot >=1.5.999.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and <2.0.0.M1`

The full output from the [Spring Starter Actuator Info](https://start.spring.io/actuator/info) page,

```
"spring-cloud": {
    "Edgware.SR5": "Spring Boot >=1.5.0.RELEASE and <=1.5.19.RELEASE",
    "Edgware.BUILD-SNAPSHOT": "Spring Boot >=1.5.999.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and <2.0.0.M1",
    "Finchley.M2": "Spring Boot >=2.0.0.M3 and <2.0.0.M5",
    "Finchley.M3": "Spring Boot >=2.0.0.M5 and <=2.0.0.M5",
    "Finchley.M4": "Spring Boot >=2.0.0.M6 and <=2.0.0.M6",
    "Finchley.M5": "Spring Boot >=2.0.0.M7 and <=2.0.0.M7",
    "Finchley.M6": "Spring Boot >=2.0.0.RC1 and <=2.0.0.RC1",
    "Finchley.M7": "Spring Boot >=2.0.0.RC2 and <=2.0.0.RC2",
    "Finchley.M9": "Spring Boot >=2.0.0.RELEASE and <=2.0.0.RELEASE",
    "Finchley.RC1": "Spring Boot >=2.0.1.RELEASE and <2.0.2.RELEASE",
    "Finchley.RC2": "Spring Boot >=2.0.2.RELEASE and <2.0.3.RELEASE",
    "Finchley.SR3": "Spring Boot >=2.0.3.RELEASE and <2.0.999.BUILD-SNAPSHOT",
    "Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT": "Spring Boot >=2.0.999.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and <2.1.0.M3",
    "Greenwich.M1": "Spring Boot >=2.1.0.M3 and <2.1.0.RELEASE",
    "Greenwich.RELEASE": "Spring Boot >=2.1.0.RELEASE and <2.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT",
    "Greenwich.BUILD-SNAPSHOT": "Spring Boot >=2.1.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
},
```