# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to add Elasticsearch to my project. I have addded the necessary dependencies to my pom.xml file. When I run the server I am getting this error:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [net.kzn.shoppingbackend.config.HibernateConfig] from ClassLoader
> [ParallelWebappClassLoader
> ```

Please help me solve this problem.

Also I tried to find elasticsearch.yml file in eclipse to configure node but there is no such file. where Can i find elasticsearch.yml file.

**HibernateConfig.java**

```
package net.kzn.shoppingbackend.config;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "net.kzn.shoppingbackend")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "net.kzn.shoppingbackend" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    // change the below based on the DBMS you choose
    private final static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/onlineshopping";
    private final static String DATABASE_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private final static String DATABASE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect";
    private final static String DATABASE_USERNAME = "sa";
    private final static String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "";

    @Value("${elasticsearch.home:/home/vidyesh/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/5.6.8}")
    private String elasticsearchHome;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.cluster.name:elasticsearch}")
    private String clusterName;

    // database bean will be available
    @Bean("dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        // providing the database connection information

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);

        return dataSource;
    }

    // sessionFactory bean will be available
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        builder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        builder.scanPackages("net.kzn.shoppingbackend");

        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    // All the hibernate properties will be returned in this method
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", DATABASE_DIALECT);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public Client client() {
        TransportClient client = null;
        try {
            final Settings elasticsearchSettings = Settings.builder()
              .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
              .put("path.home", elasticsearchHome)
              .put("cluster.name", clusterName).build();
            client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(elasticsearchSettings); 
            client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }

    // transactionManager bean
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager geTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

**Loaders.java**

```
package net.kzn.shoppingbackend.load;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import net.kzn.shoppingbackend.dto.Product;
import net.kzn.shoppingbackend.dto.Users;
import net.kzn.shoppingbackend.repository.UsersRepository;

@Component
public class Loaders {

    @Autowired
    ElasticsearchOperations operations;

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    public void loadAll(){

        operations.putMapping(Product.class);
        System.out.println("Loading Data");
        usersRepository.save(getData());
        System.out.printf("Loading Completed");

    }

    private List<Users> getData() {
        List<Users> userses = new ArrayList<>();
        userses.add(new Users("Ajay",123L, "Accounting", 12000L));
        userses.add(new Users("Jaga",1234L, "Finance", 22000L));
        userses.add(new Users("Thiru",1235L, "Accounting", 12000L));
        return userses;
    }
}
```

This is my pom.xml file

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>net.kzn</groupId>
<artifactId>shoppingbackend</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>shoppingbackend</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>5.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.6</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- JUNIT version 4.12 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- H2 database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.197</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- database connection pooling -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/transport -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.plugin/transport-netty4-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport-netty4-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Error**

```
    ERROR Context
initialization failed 19:56:48.391" o.s.web.context.ContextLoader java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Failed to introspect Class[net.kzn.shoppingbackend.config.HibernateConfig]from ClassLoader[ParallelWebappClassLoader
context:
    onlineshopping
    delegate:false---------->
Parent Classloader:java.net.URLClassLoader @24d 46 ca6]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:680)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:577)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:562)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:620)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:721)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:662)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1491)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:507)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:477)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong here? Problem is related to dependancies?

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace that you got along with the error message ?

Comment: I added full error message.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations

This error message means that the jar containing this class is not on the application classpath.

Add spring-data-elasticsearch jar to it, and your error should be gone.

if you are using maven, add the jar to the classpath this way :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The version that you should use depends on the version of elastic search you are connecting to :

```
+--------------+----------------------------+----------------+-------------+
| Spring Data  | Spring Data Elasticsearch  | Elasticsearch  | Spring Boot |
+--------------+----------------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 2021.1       | 4.3.x                      |         7.15.2 | 2.5.x       |
| 2021.0       | 4.2.x                      |         7.12.0 | 2.5.x       |
| 2020.0.0     | 4.1.x                      |          7.9.3 | 2.3.x       |
| Neumann      | 4.0.x                      |          7.6.2 | 2.3.x       |
| Moore        | 3.2.x                      |          6.8.4 | 2.2.x       |
| Lovelace     | 3.1.x                      |          6.2.2 | 2.1.x       |
| Kay          | 3.0.x                      |          5.5.0 | 2.0.x       |
| Ingalls      | 2.1.x                      |          2.4.0 | 1.5.x       |
+--------------+----------------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

(source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions )

Comment: I added spring-data-elasticsearch jar file to class path Failed to introspect Class error is gone but new error is showing

Comment: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{IQoE1_yHTfGWK_L2n5EHoQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}] 12:41:34.620" o.s.d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository

Comment: Is it correct path? @Value("${elasticsearch.home:/home/vidyesh/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/transport/6.3.2}")

Comment: @vidy you're next error message seems to say that elastic search servers you have configured in your application are not there (not started, not at this address, and / or not listening on right port). Please take also a moment to read the stackoverflow faq : to keep the site usable for everybody, comments should be related to the answer / question they are on, and not contains new questions to solve. If you have a new problem, you should raise a new question :)

Comment: just a small note, please remove the versions from your dependencies, if they are spring-* for sure, and let the parent handle them

Comment: @AbdullahKhaled The compatibility table is useful for those not using spring boot as parent artifact, to know quickly which version to include in their project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **spring-data-elasticsearch.jar** file into your class path. The error is showing because of this small mistake.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Shorten command line inside Run Configuration]

Adding shorten command line JAR manifest to run configuration solved the problem for me.