# Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration]

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I created a project with spring boot 2.1.1 and when I try to lift it I get the following error:

> 2018-12-10 19:23:14.837 ERROR 8096 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]     at
>   atuq.FrigorificoApplication.main(FrigorificoApplication.java:14)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
>   introspect Class
>   [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration]
>   from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]  at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:583)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:568)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:626)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:721)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:662)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:195)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:159)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:152)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:135)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:97)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:298)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:289)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:278)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:189)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:160)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]  ... 16
>   common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/servlet/Filter  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668)
>   ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]    ... 38 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.servlet.Filter  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_181]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>     ... 42 common frames omitted

paso el pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>atuq</groupId>
    <artifactId>frigorifico</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>frigorifico</name>
    <description>Frigorifico Malargue</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: How are you running you app when the error occurs?

Comment: I have tried several options. Right click and execute in netbeans, mvn from command line, as java project from eclipse.

Comment: It looks like Maven may have corrupted a dependency when it downloaded it. Try clearing out Maven's cache and rebuilding your app.

Comment: already clean the memory and the problem persists

Comment: Perhaps the dependency was corrupted again? With a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web`, `javax.servlet.Filter` should be on the classpath due to the starter's dependency on `tomcat-embed-core`. I would check that `mvn dependency:tree` shows that dependency and that `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.13/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar` is a valid jar file.

Comment: check this ---  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53284134/java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to-introspect-class

Answer (score 31):

If you have below dependency for spring-boot-starter-tomcat in you POM, remove scope part of it.

Existing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

New:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Worked for me, Can you please why it not worked? few months ago it worked for me

Comment: hello, I have this issue as well, while your solution has indeed solved the problem, I now have an error telling me that it's not able to start tomcat. Here's the full error msg : org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Comment: Thanks for answear! my case the version was wrong for <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>.

Answer (score 10):

The error is helpful in that it can't find the required class `javax.servlet.Filter` and a common way to have this class is through this dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

which ends up pulling in `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core`

We were seeing this locally because when running the Spring Boot application from Intellij we didn't have the option 'Include dependencies with "Provided" scope' in the Run/Debug Configuration ticked.

Answer (score 4):

I think this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Made a conflict with this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Why do you need the last one? I think you don't need it, because you already has starter for security, so remove it.

Comment: Why do you have `<type>jar</type>` for some dependencies?

Comment: I got it down like that, anyway I have them in other projects and they work that way. Remove them to try, but follow the error anyway

Comment: Can you update you questing and provide full and actual `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused when trying to reference a class which is not there. Adding this dependency fixed the error in my case:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

At the bottom of my log this had appeared:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/SecurityFilterChain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain
```

It was shown that the `org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain` class was absent.

So on some googling, I found the class was present in `spring-security-web` repository. After adding it to the dependencies in `pom.xml`, voila, the next build passed successfully.

Answer (score -2):

I encountered the same problem today. It turns out the problem was caused by the main startup class not being placed at the outermost level of the code. Make sure that you have defined the startup class at the correct location.