# Exception while starting spring boot application as jar

Tags: spring-boot

I created a jar using maven spring boot plugin and tried to run the jar using `java -jar App.jar`. The main file is configured with Spring boot and when I tried package it start the jar I am getting error as -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.database.DatabaseApplication.main(DatabaseApplication.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

This indicated that the dependency jar is missing in the packaged jar. I tried looking for various solutions on the web but to my failure none worked for me. I check the answer [NoClassDefinitonFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740703/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-boot-springapplication-mav) and [Package dependency jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) but it did not work and I ended up getting the same error everytime. Below is the build section of my pom. Can anyone please help ?

Current configuration

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                 <goals>
                   <goal>repackage</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <configuration>
                   <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                   <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                 </configuration>
               </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Other configurations

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin> 
</plugins>
```

Below is the pom.xml file without build added -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.database</groupId>
<artifactId>Database</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Database application </name>
<description>Database operations application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <start-class>com.database.App</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    ...
</build>
```

I want to package dependencies into the jar file created after running `mvn clean package`. Using terminal to build the application and not building it using eclipse.

Comment: Do you use maven, right? If yes put here you pom.xml file :)

Comment: @DinaBogdan pom pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use this configuration for build section in your pom.xml.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```