# Why JVM cannot find the definition of SpringApplication class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

It might look like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740703/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-boot-springapplication-mav) question, but the solutions from it didn't work for me. I am getting an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication at com.example.demo.Application.main` error when I try to run the application using spring-boot. My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.blog</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-8-16-springboot-webflow-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.js</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- And other dependencies -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

JDK 1.8 and JRE 8 are installed on the system and worked fine before. I deleted the `C:\Users\{username}\.M2\repository\org\springframework\boot` directory on the system and forced Maven to reload the dependencies. Then I decompiled the file `C:\Users\{username}\.M2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar` and still found it in it has this `SpringApplication` class that the JVM cannot find. I also explicitly added `spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar` to the project, but the error remained the same. There is only a suspicion that I am using Open JDK, and not Oracle, which did not install on the system, but simply downloaded the deployed files and placed them in the folder I needed (the JDK installer for some reason does not work for me). Does anyone have any suggestions on what this problem may be related to?

Comment: Do not define different versions of dependencies which are defined by spring boot for example: `spring-webflow` furthermore add the complete exception and how you have called Maven?

Comment: @khmarbaisec how I called Maven? From Eclipse IDE `Maven->Update Project` and then `Run as -> Maven Install`.Thanks for the hint. I'll try to change the versions of the dependencies.