# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**I am getting below, did anyone faced such issue, i am using spring mvc with springboot dependency.**

- I have recently upgraded my spring version to 5.3.6 and using one dependency which is springboot, i am getting below issue*

> Please help if someone faced similar issue

````
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [x.y.z.ExceptionsHandlingConfig] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader
  context: xyz-war-1.49.0-SNAPSHOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@dfd3711
]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4697) [catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5163) [catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743) [catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719) [catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) [catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970) [catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840) [catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.55]
    ... 33 common frames omitted```
````

Comment: Please refer to this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740703/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-boot-springapplication-mav

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura I tried the options mentioned in above link but no luck yet